# How to make button visible once to admin-type user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, button, admin

I want to make `ADD` button only visible to admin-type user. My code looks like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  @if(Auth::user()->type=='admin')
    <a href="{{ route('User.create', ['id'=>$user->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-default</i> ADD</a>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

But, it returns lot of `ADD` button according to number of all users because of `foreach` loop. If I remove foreach loop, it will show error:

> Undefined variable: user

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of you are removing the foreach , but using the variable `$user` again inside the `routes` .
Please remove the `$user->id` and instead, use Auth::user()->id .

```
  @if(Auth::user()->type=='admin')
    <a href="{{ route('User.create', ['id'=>Auth::user()->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-default</i> ADD</a>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use foreach loop to check authenticated user having type admin

You need to remove passing id into the user.create route

```
@if(Auth::user()->type == 'admin')
<a href="{{ route('User.create') }}" class="btn btn-default</i> ADD</a>
@endif
```